# Why do Cloud Firestore collections need at least one document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When creating a new collection, I'm told I need to create an initial document for it. I find this a bit confusing. If I'm creating a collection entitled "Messages" for a collection backing an instant-messaging window, why would I want to put an initial document in there (representing a single message) before the users have sent any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have a document to add, then don't add one.

A collection doesn't need to be created at the console at all.  They just spring into existence when a document first appears, and they vanish when the last document is deleted.  They don't need to be created and deleted like folders in a filesystem.  Just read and write them assuming that they exist.  If a collection doesn't exist, a query against it will simply return no documents.

Answer (score 0):

I presume it's the nature of the beast. Chris Esplin tells us that Firebase always follows the collection-document-collection-document pattern. Firebase Docs define collections saying, "documents live in collections, which are simply containers for documents." They define their Cloud Firestore data model as inherently schemaless, requiring unique document names. More is offered discussing hierarchical data, "Documents in Cloud Firestore should be lightweight...create additional collections within [documents] as sub collections... A subcollection is a collection associated with a specific document." Their example provides for a chat rooms collection where each room is a document with a messages subcollection wherein each document thereof is a unique 1-MB-or-less document instance of a message. "Notice the alternating pattern of collections and documents. Your collections and documents must always follow this pattern. You cannot reference a collection in a collection or a document in a document... You can nest data up to 100 levels deep." A warning is given that deleting a document does not delete its subcollections. See below for references. Sir Chris Esplin is found at fullstackfirebase.com.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#node.js
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data